# How to create table with name of the column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this

```
describe metal;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| copper   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gold     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| iron     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lead     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mercury  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| platinum | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| silver   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tin      | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

What I really want is this

```
+----------+
| name
|+----------+
| copper
| gold
| iron
| lead
| mercury 
| platinum 
| silver
| tin
```

My aim is to manipulate column by name.I have created my original table with

```
CREATE TABLE metal (name VARCHAR(20),....
```

The problem is here

```
SELECT name FROM metal WHERE name LIKE 'co%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

And copper is there so something is wrong with my creation.

Comment: actully what you need.?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking (and who upvoted this?).

Comment: This smacks of poor design. See normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Google `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but then don't use it for the reason that you seem to want here, as if I'm interpreting it correctly, that looks like awful design.

Comment: you need to arrange the order wise field.?

Comment: what does 'SELECT * FROM metal' return for you?

Comment: I think he's trying to add the "copper", "gold", ... as records but is adding them as columns instead. Am I the only one confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normalised design might look like this:

```
metals (id*, name)
```

where * is a PRIMARY KEY

So:

```
           id name 
           29 copper   
           79 gold     
           26 iron     
           82 lead     
           80 mercury  
           78 platinum 
           47 silver   
           50 tin
```

Answer (score 1):

Create table like this:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | varchar(20) | NO   | YES |         |       |
```

And then you can add in this table different names of metal: copper, gold, iron with INSERT statement.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment, you have a column/field actually called "name". Delete the "name" column if you don't want it.

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |  <------
| copper   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```